# MacOS - Are my pip and pip3 locations correct?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am new to python (not new to programming) and unfortunately butchered my previous python 3.7 installation while figuring things out. Long story short, I ended up deleting and reinstalling pip3, which in turn made the standard pip command (for the 2.7 pre-installed version of python o macOS) not exist. I've managed to get both installed again but am concerned with their locations.

My question is regarding the locations of both pip and pip3 when running the `pip --version` as well as the `pip3 --version` command.

Below is the output for these commands:

```
pip --version

pip 19.3.1 from /Users/Wyatt/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)


pip3 --version

pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

I believe `pip3` is in the correct location, but feel that the `pip` command should not be located inside of my user library, but the system library like `pip3`. Is this correct, and if not, how can I fix this?

Comment: You have installed `pip` for Python 2.7 as user, there's nothing wrong with that if that's what you mean. BTW 2.7 will be EOL in three days anyway.

Answer (score 0):

On my local machine MacOs the default `pip` resides at the following location

```
pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
```

And after installing python3 using [HomeBrew](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/) `brew install python3`, `pip3` location is the following.

```
pip3 --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```